# How can I jump to the beginning of the loop?

Tags: php

This is the simplified of my code:

```
$html = "";
$posts = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while ( $post = array_shift($posts) ){

    if ( $post['deleted'] == true ){

        /* jump to the four lines above (while)
         * to ignore this post, becuase it is deleted
         */
    }

    $html .= '<div class="content">' . $content . '</div>';

}
```

As I've commented in the middle of my code, I need to go to the upper lines. Is it possible?

---

Noted that in the example I mention above, I can put `$html .= ...` line into `else {}` block. But in reality everything is more complicated that doing such a thing won't work. All I need to know is something like jumping to up in PHP?

Comment: shouldn't be that the `->fetch()` is supposed to be inside the while condition? (so that it continually fetch the rows until it runs out) and can you elaborate what _I need to go to the upper lines_ mean

Comment: what do you mean by "I need to go to the upper lines" what upper lines?

Comment: I mean I want to tell to compiler, go to the line `while ( ...`

Comment: [php goto syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) But this is not recommended in high level programming language, just for your reference.

Comment: can you give a little bit of context of why would you need such thing? by the way, you can explicitly change the current pointer on the fetch method, just add that parameter its in the docs

Answer (score 3):

You can use `continue` keywords may be help,As i understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

why not do it like this:

```
for($i=4;$i<count($posts);$i++)
{
    if ($current['deleted'] === true) 
    {
      $i -= 4; // jump back
    }
    $current = $posts[$i];

    $html .= '<div class="content">' . $content . '</div>';
}
```

EDIT: all you need is the continue statement..